# Geoserver - error load page postgis connection

Tags: heroku, deployment, postgis, geoserver

in geoserver when I create new workspace or new Postgis connection i get error 400 bad request, i've deployed geoserver 2.16.2 in Heroku. I've tried to deploy in my localhost with tomcat 8.5 and it works well.

Comment: What are your Postgres and Postgis versions?
Have you checked the DB connection on Heroku? Does it work?

Comment: i use external postgres database, when i connect to my server i get error 400 bad request, the same when i create new workspace. I've tried to deploy all version of geoserver till 2.4.8 and that it works. Is geoserver problem or settings?

Comment: On your local machine Geoserver works, is it right?
Does old Geoserver version  work on Heroku the ?

Comment: yes version 2.16 and 2.4 work on my local machine and versione 2.4 work on heroku but from 2.5 and 2.17 (include 2.6,2.7 ecc ) didn't work.

Comment: you're talking of 400 bad request. Where do you see it? Do you see it on Geoserver admin GUI?

Comment: Yes. example i log in in admin geoserver gui, go to new data source and when i click on postgis i get error 400 bad request.

Comment: It is very strange. It could be a trouble with Heroku integration, with load balancing for example. How many nodes are you using for geoserver?

Comment: nodes? i only deploy yhe app with heroku war:deploy geoserver.war --app <appName> and try to load somethings

Comment: Is your app scaled? Are there some replicas?

Comment: No i just take the war file from http://geoserver.org/release/stable/ and deploy it, as described in installation manual. It the limits of the page cache? i solve it change dyno tipes?

Comment: It is very strange, I think that it depends on heroku proxy. You could try to see the dyno log in order to verify the request url sent. If there is a bad request, the url  could be rewrited from gateway